# The location to paste public keys

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, centos

I am learning ansible and I need certificate based authentication between server and clients.
I see in many articles that the .pub key should be copied to .ssh/authorized_keys.
However I wanted to know is that to be done for a users or root.
If its root then the path will be /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
If its a normal user the path will be /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
Where should the keys be pasted to? Are the path mentioned above correct? If not what should be the correct path?

Answer (score 1):

If your ansible_user is root, then the correct path is: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Otherwise is like you said: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Thank you Giuseppe for your reply. So I have two machines source server is A and connecting to server B. Server A has a user Alpha and that account does not exist on server B. Do I need to create an account for Alpha on server B. Once created should I copy the public key from Server A to its ServerB:/home/Alpha/.ssh/authorized_keys?  Can it work without creating an account for Alpha on server B?

Comment: Hello, If you want the same username for connecting, then you have to create the new user in server B and then put the keys like you said ServerB:/home/Alpha/.ssh/authorized_keys
To check if it is working you can perform a test with ssh from server A (ssh Alpha@ServerB_IP echo Hello), if it works, than you can test a ping with ansible with  : ansible ServerB_IP -u Alpha -m ping